# Dual monitor setup issue - Both monitors detected but 2nd screen Is black

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I recently upgraded my computer from using onboard graphics to a GTX 960 ([GV-N960OC-4GD](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5507#ov)).

I previously had a dual monitor setup, with my primary monitor (SyncMaster2233sw) using a DVI cable and the secondary monitor (Syncmaster 173v) using a VGA cable. I purchased a DVI to VGA adapter to connect the secondary monitor, and while it detects the monitor the screen remains black as if it is in standby mode.

[image: Screenshot]

I can even move windows and my mouse onto the second monitor, however it obviously just disappears from sight. I've also tried switching the cables to see if it was a faulty port, however my primary monitor works in both, just the secondary that remains black.

Any help would be much appreciated!

NVIDIA Control Panel:

[image]

GPU drivers:

[image]

**UPDATE**: The problem was just a faulty VGA-to-DVI adapter. That's what I get for buying it off eBay I guess.

**UPDATE 2**: It turns out that I needed a DVI-I adapter as my secondary screen apparently only accepts analogue output whereas I was using a DVI-D (digital) adapter.

Comment: Have you tried using the nvidia controlpanel to do the dual monitor setup.

Comment: @JelloDude Yes, it says it's detected so I'm not really sure what else I can do. See here: http://puu.sh/lIRpK.png

Comment: Try changing it's resolution and refresh rate.

Comment: I use a similar card "Gigabyte GeForce GTX 960 - WindForce 2X OC" and there was no need to  use the Nvidia control panel. The regular windows tools *should* be able to handle this just fine.

Q: Did you try the DVI-I to VGA convertor with the old setup to make sure that one is working?

Comment: @JelloDude Yeah, I've tried every option for resolution and frequency (60 and 75Hz) available and it hasn't had an effect.

Comment: @Hennes I haven't attempted that yet because it would mean I have to reinstall my old graphics drivers and remove my graphics card. However I just tried using the adapter on my old computer set up (which has the same model primary monitor using a VGA cable) and the screen didn't turn on, which would suggest the adapter may be faulty. Will wait for any other suggestions, if not I guess I'll buy another one and see.

Comment: Could you also please double check in **Device manager** that you are using manufacturer's driver and not the generic one from Microsoft.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík I assume I am as under Monitors they are both listed as "Generic PnP monitor". I have attempted to install the driver for the secondary secondary monitor which I found online, however I don't think it is supported on windows 7, as I get a it is a very old monitor and I get this error the second I try and open it: http://puu.sh/lITdO.jpg

Comment: @user529584 That might not be problem, I meant the graphics card driver, not the actual monitors.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík I'm fairly certain it is running off the graphics card driver as I installed the drivers from the disc and updated everything. Here's what comes up under device manager: http://puu.sh/lIUTR.png

Comment: @user529584, yes, that seems just fine.

Comment: I just noticed that your card has a "1" and a "2" next to the DVI outputs. I have similar markings on my own card and that one only allows me to use ports from "set 1" or from "set 2".  I have problem finding information on that on Gigabytes website though. I also do not see a dotted line, which I do see on the 960. (http://i.stack.imgur.com/kHXjb.png)

Comment: @Hennes Interesting, I do recall the description of the eBay listing I bought the card from saying it could support up to 4 monitors, but then again I'm sure they wouldn't be the most accurate source of information. However it still doesn't explain why I can't get the screen to work in either DVI ports without my primary monitor plugged in. At this point I might just waste another couple dollars on another adapter and hope for the best. Thanks for all your help, as well as for editing of my post, I'm new here so not really sure on the post rules and expectations.

Comment: Update: I managed to find another DVI to VGA cable which I didn't realise I had lying around which worked straight away. That's what I get for trying to save money with eBay I guess.

Comment: The site's Q&A format relies on questions being just questions and answers being solutions to them.  Including an answer within the question makes the question unclear, and others can't search for the answer.  Instead, please post the answer as an answer (read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using a Windows machine, try the following:

1. See if the connections are correct.
2. Press Windows key + P.
3. Select duplicate or extend options.
4. Even now if the screen does not appear then check if you have powered on the 2nd monitor.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed mine by turning off monitor, plugging the hdmi cable out of the laptop. Then turned off the main power switch for the monitor and waited for about 20 sec. Turned back on the power switch. Turned back on the monitor and insert the hdmi cable back into the laptop. Andddd it suddenly appeared on the other monitor too.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, that the second monitor is not listed in the device manager.

Check if the current screen settings for your second monitor are actually supported by it (screen resolution, refresh rate).

Then try to swap monitors (change their order of 1 and 2 internally in Windows only) and see, if the second one is actually responding.

If that doesn't help, change their connections on your PC - maybe the second DVI-out out is somehow ... "broken".

If the second monitor still stays black - get a new one ;-)

Sometimes my second monitor isn't available too and flickrs (?) all around. Then i just turn it off and on again and then it is recognized by Windows.

But there might also be a wrong setting that prevents outputting video information on the second DVI-out. You might double check your setting within nVidia Control Panel and the (usually) built-in Intel Graphics Control panel or whatever.

Comment: Oh sorry that's my bad, I'd unplugged the screen to test it in the other port and forgot to plug it back in. They do both come up though as "Generic PnP Monitor". I know the screen itself isn't broken because it was working with on-board graphics from the motherboard before I installed the new graphics card.

Comment: The check your graphic card settings. Oviously there's something wrong. Not sure, if there might be a "hardware setting" on the card itself, to support both DVI-outs, like a jumper or anything.

Answer (score 0):

There exist "video range extender" solutions which connect signals directly to a different cable style, without changing the signal format.  This is useful if, for example, you have long VGA cables permanently installed inside the walls of your room, because you can use the existing cable to carry DVI or HDMI data.  But you must use the corresponding adapter to change the signal back to its original connector type, that matches the signal encoding.  You can't expect to connect directly to a device supporting the new connector format, since it also expects a different signal encoding.

While a DVI-I to VGA connector is also passive (no re-encoding), use of the analog pins in the DVI-I connector signal to the video source to generate VGA (analog) signalling instead of DVI, so that the monitor receives a real VGA signal as it expects.

Another thing to try if whether your second monitor has an "input" or "source" button.  If your monitor is displaying from DVI in but you've hooked up its VGA cable, then you would not get any picture.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. Found the solution which is to right click on the 2nd monitor -> Properties -> Under the Adapter tab -> List All Modes and change it to 16 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, all I did was press the monitor menu buttons on the physical monitor and it magically starting displaying and no longer blank.

I was about to try and reset to factory defaults as I read elsewhere on the web might work, but now... I don't need to.

Hope this helps someone :).

Answer (score 0):

In the monitor menu, I changed the input port version from HDMI 2 to HDMI 1.4 and it worked

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.